# moving a circle backward when hitting the canvas x border

Tags: javascript, canvas

this is my jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/seekpunk/s54RM/

as you can see when the circle is hitting the x border it stuck there how should i modify my update function to make it move backward when hitting the border :

```
 if(Bluecircle.x==xborder) {                  
    Bluecircle.x -= 0.5;
 }
 else {
    Bluecircle.x += 0.5;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the direction as a variable, and flip its sign when the border-hit condition is met.

```
var xDir = 0.5;

// ... then in your update function

if(Bluecircle.x>=xborder || Bluecircle.x <= 0) {
  xDir *= -1;
}

Bluecircle.x += xDir;
```

This will bounce off both the left & right sides of the screen.